# Динамический ипорт или как вызвать функцию из пакета не зная название пакета

Tags: php, golang

Вопрос следующий, недавно начал изучать Go, столкнулся с такой проблемой
В пхп это реализуется следующим образом

```
$db['class_name'] = 'ClassA'; // например получили название класса из бд

$classes = ['ClassA', 'ClassB']; // массив доступных классов

$object = new $classes[$db['class_name']] // создаем нужный класс
```

В Go нашел только одно решение (использование плагинов), но к сожалению они работают только под Linux

Например код:

```
package company_one

import "fmt"

type CompanyOne struct{}

func (company *CompanyOne) Init() {
    fmt.Println("Hello CompanyOne")
}
```

```
package company_two

import "fmt"

type CompanyTwo struct{}

func (company *CompanyTwo) Init() {
    fmt.Println("Hello CompanyTwo")
}
```

```
package main

import (
    "strings"
    _ "company_one"
    _ "company_two"
)

func main() {
   //data["CLIENT"] приходит или company_one или company_two, в зависимости от клиента
   client_name := strings.ToLower(data["CLIENT"].(string))
   client_name.Init()
}
```

как мне вызвать функцию из пакета?

Comment: Создайте [фабрику](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/factory-method/go/example) классов, в которую будут импортироваться нужные вам классы, и используйте её для создания объекта но названию.

Comment: @stanislav вы поняли о чем говорил @Daniel?